# PHP Foreach erroring out on last subarray

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and I'm using multidimensional arrays to process events. 
For some reason when I'm using the Foreach function it will throw an error for the last subarray. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

The multiple dimensional array is below. The keys are in order event_id, day, track and session.

```
Array
(
[718] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [1745] => Array
                            (
                                [session_id] => 1745
                                [event_start_date] => 2010-12-02 09:00
                                [session_position] => 1
                            )

                        [1554] => Array
                            (
                                [session_id] => 1554
                                [event_start_date] => 2010-12-02 09:00
                                [session_position] => 2
                            )

                        [1557] => Array
                            (
                                [session_id] => 1557
                                [event_start_date] => 2010-12-02 09:00
                                [session_position] => 3
                            )

                        [1678] => Array
                            (
                                [session_id] => 1678
                                [event_start_date] => 2010-12-02 09:00
                                [session_position] => 4
                            )

                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [1555] => Array
                            (
                                [session_id] => 1555
                                [event_start_date] => 2010-12-02 09:00
                                [session_position] => 1
                            )

                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [1649] => Array
                            (
                                [session_id] => 1649
                                [event_start_date] => 2010-12-02 09:00
                                [session_position] => 1
                            )

                        [1672] => Array
                            (
                                [session_id] => 1672
                                [event_start_date] => 2010-12-02 09:00
                                [session_position] => 2
                            )

                        [1651] => Array
                            (
                                [session_id] => 1651
                                [event_start_date] => 2010-12-02 09:00
                                [session_position] => 3
                            )

                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [1559] => Array
                            (
                                [session_id] => 1559
                                [event_start_date] => 2010-12-02 09:00
                                [session_position] => 1
                            )

                        [1669] => Array
                            (
                                [session_id] => 1669
                                [event_start_date] => 2010-12-02 09:00
                                [session_position] => 2
                            )

                        [1650] => Array
                            (
                                [session_id] => 1650
                                [event_start_date] => 2010-12-02 09:00
                                [session_position] => 3
                            )

                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [1652] => Array
                            (
                                [session_id] => 1652
                                [event_start_date] => 2010-12-02 09:00
                                [session_position] => 1
                            )

                        [1561] => Array
                            (
                                [session_id] => 1561
                                [event_start_date] => 2010-12-02 09:00
                                [session_position] => 2
                            )

                        [1654] => Array
                            (
                                [session_id] => 1654
                                [event_start_date] => 2010-12-02 09:00
                                [session_position] => 3
                            )

                    )

                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [1638] => Array
                            (
                                [session_id] => 1638
                                [event_start_date] => 2010-12-02 09:00
                                [session_position] => 1
                            )

                        [1556] => Array
                            (
                                [session_id] => 1556
                                [event_start_date] => 2010-12-02 09:00
                                [session_position] => 2
                            )

                        [1653] => Array
                            (
                                [session_id] => 1653
                                [event_start_date] => 2010-12-02 09:00
                                [session_position] => 3
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

)

I'm using the following code to display the array (I will be processing it once my bug is fixed)

```
reset($rec_info); // the above array
foreach ($rec_info as $rec_event => $event_details) {
    echo "event is: " . $rec_event . "<br />";
    foreach ($event_details as $rec_day => $day_details){
        echo "day is: " . $rec_day . "<br />";
        foreach ($day_details as $rec_track => $track_details){
            echo "track is: " . $rec_track . "<br />"; 
            foreach ($track_details as $rec_session => $session_details) {
                echo "session_id is: " . $session_details["session_id"]. "<br />"; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This displays

```
event is: 718
day is: 1
track is: 1
session_id is: 1745
session_id is: 1554
session_id is: 1557
session_id is: 1678
track is: 2
session_id is: 1555
track is: 3
session_id is: 1649
session_id is: 1672
session_id is: 1651
day is: 2

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/dev/global.php on line 349
```

When processing other events (between 2-5 days) it is always the last day that it will throw this warning.

I don't understand why the code works for the all the other days but not the last one. It is as if the array has gone over bounds. I can display all the subarrays correctly using print_r except for the the day eg:

```
echo "<hr> tracks : <pre>"; print_r($track_details); echo "</pre> <br />";
```

Comment: Hi The Line is             foreach ($day_details as $rec_track => $track_details){

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [PHP manual for foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

> ***foreach*** works only on arrays and objects, and will issue an error when
> you try to use it on a variable with a different data type or an
> uninitialized variable.

You need to check if they are valid arrays before trying to loop a non-array with `foreach()`.

```
<?php

reset($rec_info); // the above array
if(is_array($rec_info)){
 foreach ($rec_info as $rec_event => $event_details) {
 echo "event is: " . $rec_event . "<br />";
 if(is_array($event_details)){
  foreach ($event_details as $rec_day => $day_details){
  echo "day is: " . $rec_day . "<br />";
  if (is_array($day_details)){
   foreach ($day_details as $rec_track => $track_details){
   echo "track is: " . $rec_track . "<br />"; 
    if(is_array($track_details)){
     foreach ($track_details as $rec_session => $session_details) {
     echo "session_id is: " . $session_details["session_id"]. "<br />"; 
     }
    }
   }
  }
  }
 }
 } 
}
?>
```

Check the database or the initial array for any abnormalities (unexpected or unclosed records). It's likely line `348` or `349`. A proper text editor with PHP tagging should highlight the error if it's a syntax error.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help - I check my arrays with your suggestions and found that the $rec_day was not valid for the last entry only. I realised that I was using $rec_day in a previous Foreach loop (as a reference - foreach ($rec_info as &$rec_day)) and when I changed it to a new unique name the code worked fine. No idea why though.